# Can webform-civicrm pre-select an event using Drupal Views?

Tags: webform-civicrm, drupal-views

The answer is (I hope) 'yes' but I can't get it to work - see [How to select a default event in webform where event is repeating](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6706)
 I'm pretty sure the Views side is working as it generated a url that when clicked gave me the webform with the correct event selected (this is on a Views screen).  But when I run the webform I get '- None -' displayed in the event list box. Yes, I have checked "Allow events to be autoloaded from URL checked."  Code is at the latest level - I went back to Webform 7.4.9 and Webform 7.4.11 to see if there had been a regression but no change.
So now I'm wondering if this is a bug in Webform-CiviCRM?

Comment: What exactly is the url argument you are giving it?

Comment: The url in rewrite section of the global custom text field is node/27?event1=[id]
Which doesn't square with the help in webform which shows 2 event ids (but that didn't work either). This is where I am registering all contacts for the same event, although there is only one contact in this case.

Comment: And is [id] one of the available events in the select field? It won't pick something that's not there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I just clicked on the first of the listed events in the Views screen and it gave me this url https://www.dcm-admin.org.uk/node/25?event1=163   - this is the correct event.  But when I run the webform it doesn't pick this or any event.

Comment: I mean, have you added a "select" field to the webform containing that event as one of the options?

Comment: Yes, it's a list box, with 'Live Options' selected.  It lists all the events (over 100) but doesn't select one, just shows '- None - '

Comment: I just tested it on my local and the autofill does work. Ensure that you have "register all contacts for the same event(s)" as that's the format you're using. If you are using "register each contact separately" then the link needs to be node/27?c1event1=[id]

Comment: I have that option checked,  and my url is correct but no dice! Any other suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32280/discussion-between-andy-clark-and-coleman).

Comment: I found a workaround for this problem - set a default event (in the past), and have 'Show Past Events' set as 'None'.  Then the 'next' event will be selected rather than none.  So maybe no need for the Views stuff, which I could not get working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been implemented now so that there is a setting on the Event section of the webform's civicrm tab so that you can 'allow events to be autoloaded from URL'