# Create Selection Box by Using WebForms From Data Coming From CiviCRM

Tags: webform-civicrm

I want to create selection box on webforms from data coming from CiviCRM for login users. Is there any way (for example form elements, add-on, settings) to get user data from CiviCRM and use these data inside Webforms.

Comment: it is possible to prefill data on a webform with data that is already in civi for an existing contact. but i am not sure what your scenario requires. can you spell it out in your question with specific example (requires the webform_civicrm module!)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your support and interest . I want to list the name of  attended events of contact as options (selection box).

Comment: and what will the outcome of the next step be, eg if Pete attended Orange, Blue and Green. and on this form you (or he) selected Green, what would happen (since he is already registered, what difference will this make?

Comment: It is very good point :) We send evaluation form to event attendees after events. In order to distinguish evalution forms we should know which event user gives feedback.

Comment: see my reply here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7935/can-webform-civicrm-pre-select-an-event-using-drupal-views means you should be able to send them a link with the event id in the url so that it is selected when the form loads

Comment: You could probably use Drupal Webforms + it's integration with the Form Processor for that: Send out an email including the IDs you needed for your use case and a checksum which can be generated by token. Than you prefill your feedback form using the form processor and make sure you check the checksum against the contact id in both steps (retrieval of defaults and submission).

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate time that you put on this issue. How can I secure data sending from URL?  Is there any way to encrypted url string.

Comment: fyi - this does not seem like an ANSWER - if it is not pls repost as a comment or as a separate question